# How do I set current-directory in Vim to different Volumes, ex. USB drive, in macOS?

Tags: vim

I am still a new(er) user to Vim. I switch between systems frequently and rely on a USB drive to assist me. In Linux I can set my default programs to Vim, however can't in Mac.

The solution I've found is

```
:set path+=**
```

as a cross-platform utility w/

```
:find
```

to help me get files opened in Vim. However, since the current-directory is generally set to the current user, I have difficulty using this to its full potential.

I have tried "cd" in my ~/.vimrc w/ various following scripts

```
$ cd ~/Volume/Volumes/USB
$ cd ~/Volumes/USB
```

, etc., to no luck. I'm still trying to do Vim in vanilla thru the "~/.vimrc" file and am not really looking for plugins or a GUI-interface. Is there a "cd" that I can place in macOS and Linux "~/.vimrc" files to set a secondary-drive as my current-directory?

(Apologies if already answered, however I could not find this anywhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Volumes` directory is not in your `$HOME`. It's in `/` so you only have to use the right path:

```
cd /Volumes/USB
```

This scheme is specific to Mac OS X, though: if you want the same behavior on Linux you will have to find out how your distribution/DE does it.

Anyway, you should consider using Vim and the command-line how they are supposed to be used:

```
$ cd /Volumes/USB
$ vim somefile
```